# Forward Error Correction and Packet Order Correction

Tags: wireless, forward

This article lists 2 techniques used to improve wireless throughput, Forward Error Correction and Packet Order Correction.

http://www.enterprisenetworksandservers.com/monthly/art.php?3514

Does anyone know how to enable them?

Comment: That's an interesting question, because those two technologies are mostly at the research level at this point. But, I did find a company that produces products supporting them, today, which I included in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, their product is WAN only, not wireless.

Answer (score 0):

Well for WAN FEC and POC, you need a piece of network hardware (an appliance) that does this. Here is one from Silver Peak:

[Silver Peak Systems](http://www.silver-peak.com/Technology/network_integrity.htm)

I know your question was related to **wireless**, but I don't think such an appliance/router exists yet for this market.